# Copying from a dynamic array to another dynamic array in c++ fpermissive

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a array whose size is determined in runtime.

```
cout<<"Enter size of array: ";
cin>>size1;
int* scores=new int[size1];
```

Then I fill up this array scores. Now I want to increase its size. I create a new dynamic array.

```
int* newScores=new int[newSize1];  
such that `newSize1 > Size1
```

Now I copy content of old scores into newScores:

```
for(int i=0; i<Size1;i++)
{newScores[i] = scores[i];
}
```

Now I have to ask remaining element of newScores to add to it. 
I did:

```
for(int j=size1;j<newSize1;j++)
{
newScores[j]=new int;
cout<<"Enter new score: ";
cin>>newScores[j];
}
```

While I compile it, I get the above error:
`error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
       newScores[size1]=new int;`

Comment: This isn't Java. `newScores[j] = new int;` makes no sense. Remove it. There's already space for an `int` there.

Comment: C++ isn't Java or C#. You'd just create objects, e.g., using `int()` instead of `new int` (the latter would also leave the value uninitialized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newScores[j]=new int;` is an error, and not necessary. `newscores[j]` is a lvlalue `int`, while `new int` returns `int*`. But you already have no need to allocate it - you did it in the `int* newScores=new int[newSize1];` expression.

You could avoid the thole hassle by using [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It resizes itself automatically as you insert elements into it (with `push_back`), and you don't have to worry about releasing the memory yourself.

Comment: I am not allowed to use vector.

Comment: Then just remove the unnecessary line.

Comment: `int* newScoresArrDyn = new int[newNumberOfScores];  
       if(newNumberOfScores<=nscores)    
 {
    for(int i=0;i<newNumberOfScores;i++)  
    {  
      newScoresArrDyn[i] = scores[i];  
    }  
 }`

Why does this part produce segmentation fault?

Comment: @SulavTimsina You're accessing the old `scores` `newNumberOfScores` times - and you didn't have that many elements there

Comment: How am i doing so?I have not written anything like scores[nweNumberOfScore]  any where.
I have paste-d my code in paste bin. Please have a look at it.
http://pastebin.com/vnhdyxMt  
http://pastebin.com/5TEvFw2z  
http://pastebin.com/RvMzxJVq

Comment: @SulavTimsina `int* newScoresArrDyn = new int[3];` You need to allocate `newNumbrOfScores`, not `3`. Btw you don't set the new array and size to your student.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125811/discussion-between-sulav-timsina-and-krzaq).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
newScores[j]=new int;
```

Comment: Does that compile?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Nope, that should puke with the identical error (and rightly so).

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's c#

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to assign new int to your dynamic array again. Besides, you need to delete the memory by using delete[] when you use dynamic array

Comment: Please look my code. pastebin.com/vnhdyxMt  pastebin.com/5TEvFw2z  pastebin.com/RvMzxJVq